# php equilvalant to on duplicate key update?

Tags: php

I find myself using this logic a lot:

```
if (isset($array[$key]))
        $array[$key] += $num;
else
        $array[$key]  = $num;
```

since the keys are dynamically generated I cannot just set them all to zero at the start.

I was wondering if there were a more elegant way of doing this, similar to MySQLs `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` logic.

Comment: That's pretty much how mysql does it as well. Check if the key exists, do an insert query if not, otherwise do an update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently dont think, there are *really* cooler solutions. Maybe some are more or less readable

```
if (!isset($array[$key])) $array[$key] = 0;
$array[$key] += $num
```

or

```
$array[$key] = isset($array[$key])
             ? $array[$key] + $num
             : $num;
```

Little update:
If you  set `error_reporting` to a value, that dont show notices

```
$array[$key] += $num;
```

is also possible, but its not a very good idea to produce code, that intentionaly throws notices.

Comment: suspected as much. well then: I propose a new set of operators like so: `=+=`,`=-=`,`=/=`,`=*=`,`=.=`. cool?

Comment: Dont think so, the existing ones are ok ;) I would prefer, if `$array['unknown']` would just stop throwing a notice. It returns `null` anyway and `null + 14 === 14` in the php world.

Comment: What do you mean you propose a new operator?

Answer (score 0):

you can try making a function for it:

```
setKey($array, $key, $num);

function setKey(&$array, $key, $num = 1){
   $array[$key] = (!isset($array[$key])?setKey($array,$key,$num++):$num;
}
```

recursive, but it should work.

Comment: As far as I can see this is an infinite loop, if the key exists. Whats the recursion good for?

Comment: Now its a syntax error. What you are trying?! And really: Whats the recursion good for?

Comment: destroying the world!!! moo hahaha. i have to fix it one more sec im not sure why those parens were there